# How to open files from resource folder in sbt/apache flink project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, resources, sbt, apache-flink

I am working on a scala-based project using *apache flink*, and so far I only ran my project from within `IntelliJ`, which worked without issues. Now that I am for the first time creating a JAR file which shall then be executed by the *apache flink* runtime, I run across issues with opening resource files.

At startup, a file named `setup.xml` from within `src/main/resources` is going to be opened. This works in `IntelliJ`, but not in the flink runtime.

In `IntelliJ`, the folder structure is like:

```
root
\
 src
   \
    main
     \
      resources
       \
        setup.xml
```

When looking at the created JAR file using some archive explorer, the structure will be like:

```
root
\
 [...]
\
 setup.xml
```

Code variants for this I have tried:

```
// by path
val filePath = getClass.getResource("/setup.xml").getPath
val currentPath = Paths.get(filePath)
val parsed = XML.loadFile(currentPath.toString)

// by URI
val filePath = getClass.getResource("/setup.xml").toURI
val currentPath = Paths.get(filePath)
val parsed = XML.loadFile(currentPath.toString)

// with classloader
val filePath = getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("setup.xml").toURI
val currentPath = Paths.get(filePath)
val parsed = XML.loadFile(currentPath.toString)
```

All 3 variants work in `IntelliJ`, but not the flink runtime. It will give `java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException` or `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Note that the following **will** work in both `IntelliJ` AND the flink runtime:

```
val source = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/setup.xml"))
val parsed = XML.loadString(source.getLines().mkString)
```

**However**, I **must** have access to path components, and work with combining/resolving paths. This is because the XML file will contain links to other files, beeing stored relatively to the `setup.xml` file itself. Thus, I need to get the file-path of `setup.xml`, and resolve `some-referenced.xml` with this file-path to open it.

So how would I correctly use one of the 3 variants in the beginning using the `Path` class, so I can dynamically resolve other file-paths in both `IntelliJ` as well as the flink runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for reading an CSV file I have used in previous projects:

```
private val irisDS = env.readCsvFile[Iris](getClass.getResource("/iris.dat").getPath) map { tuple ⇒
    val list = tuple.productIterator.toList
    val numList = list map (_.asInstanceOf[Double])
    LabeledVector(numList(4), DenseVector(numList.take(4).toArray))
}
```

Maybe you have declared incorrectly in your SBT the Flink dependencies, I have them like this:

```
val flinkDependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % flinkVersion % "compile",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-ml" % flinkVersion % "compile",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-scala"  % flinkVersion  % "compile"
)
```

Although, I think that when I executed the project on apache flink runtime I had to read the files externally, not from the resources folder, maybe my file [Setup.scala](https://github.com/elbaulp/DPASF/blob/master/dpasf/src/main/scala/com/elbauldelprogramador/Setup.scala) helps you.

Comment: Well, you are using the flink API to create a `DataStream` from a CSV file, using the resource. This is probably equal to my fourth solution, and thus not viable for my requirements (resolve relative file-paths).